VS Code devcontainer costs a lot of memory
As the title suggests, I am using VS Code with the devcontainers extension and CLI. I set the resources of the Docker engine to cap at 4 cores, 8GB or RAM and 15-25GB of disk.
Everything was going fine, until I had to work on multiple services when I found out that a single instance of VS Code opened in a devcontainer takes between 500 MB to 800 MB. Keep in mind that 15 services that starts from a docker-compose file takes only 156 MB of storage.
I am going to point out that the containers from the build are tinkered towards memory optimization so I am not surprised that the devcontainer one takes more memory, but 800MB is a bit excessive...
Here is the JSON configuration of the container:
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/typescript-node
{
  "name": "Babylon Vault",
  "runArgs": [
    "--name",
    "hamlet",
    "--network=hamlet-dev"
  ],
  // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:1-20-bullseye",
  "containerEnv": {
    "NODE_ENV": "docker"
  },
  // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
  // "features": {},
  // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
  "forwardPorts": [
    6100
  ],
  "appPort": [
    "6100:6100"
  ],
  // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
  "postCreateCommand": "sh .devcontainer/scripts/post-create.sh",
  "mounts": [
    "source=${env:HOME}/.ssh,target=/home/node/.ssh,type=bind,readonly"
  ],
  // Configure tool-specific properties.
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "settings": {
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Vim Deep Dark",
        "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
          "textMateRules": [
            {
              "scope": [
                "comment",
                "keyword",
                "variable.language"
              ],
              "settings": {
                "fontStyle": ""
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "editor.fontSize": 13,
        "editor.fontFamily": "'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'",
        "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons"
      },
      "extensions": [
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
        "aaron-bond.better-comments",
        "rubiin.nestjs",
        "christian-kohler.path-intellisense",
        "christian-kohler.npm-intellisense",
        "vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons",
        "johnpapa.vscode-peacock",
        "vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons",
        "drKnoxy.vscode-rainbow-brackets",
        "ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next",
        "HarryHopkinson.vim-theme"
      ]
    }
  }
  // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
  // "remoteUser": "vscode"
}

I will like to point out that my VS Code has different profiles so I don't crowd the default one with extensions in order to keep it as light as possible.
Maybe I am doing something wrong...
